# running a python script as administrator

Tags: python, windows-installer, py2exe

i'm writing an installer using py2exe which needs to run in admin to have permission to perform various file operations.  i've modified some sample code from the user_access_controls directory that comes with py2exe to create the setup file.  creating/running the generated exe works fine when i run it on my own computer.  however, when i try to run the exe on a computer that doesn't have python installed, i get an error saying that the import modules (shutil and os in this case) do not exist.  it was my impression that py2exe automatically wraps all the file dependencies into the exe but i guess that this is not the case.  py2exe does generate a zip file called library that contains all the python modules but apparently they are not used by the generated exe.  basically my question is how do i get the imports to be included in the exe generated by py2exe.  perhaps modification need to be made to my setup.py file - the code for this is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# The targets to build
# create a target that says nothing about UAC - On Python 2.6+, this
# should be identical to "asInvoker" below.  However, for 2.5 and
# earlier it will force the app into compatibility mode (as no
# manifest will exist at all in the target.)
t1 = dict(script="findpath.py",
          dest_base="findpath",
          uac_info="requireAdministrator")
console = [t1]

# hack to make windows copies of them all too, but
# with '_w' on the tail of the executable.
windows = [{'script': "findpath.py",
            'uac_info': "requireAdministrator",
            },]

setup(
    version = "0.5.0",
    description = "py2exe user-access-control",
    name = "py2exe samples",
    # targets to build
    windows = windows,
    console = console,
    )
```

Comment: Are you using the whole folder of files?  It is not enough to just copy over the .exe and .zip.

Comment: yes i'm copying the entire "dist" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `options={'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},` and `zipfile = None` in setup section. Python will make single .exe file without dependencies. Example:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['watt.py'],
    options={'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None
)
```

Comment: it says "bundle files 1 not yet supported on win64" - i'll try and install 32-bit versions of everything and see what happens

Comment: Yeah.. I didn't know that. _On win64, complain if bundle_files < 3.  This is not yet supported since the code in source\MemoryModule.c does not work on win64._ (taken from [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=640751))

Comment: hmm, it still only works on computers with python installed.  the only difference is that now there are no error messages thrown.  it just runs as if everything worked fine but doesn't do anything.  i suspect that the bundled file still isn't including the file dependencies.

Comment: I've just took a little application (watt.py) `print("Hello World!")`
Then used file setup.py exact from my anwer, typed `>python setup.py py2exe`
Got dependencies on watt.exe. It depends on msvcr90.dll and kernel32.dll only.
Could you please repeat steps to insure we have same results?

Comment: I made an experiment and think that bundle files is necessary but not enough, `zipfile = None` seems also required. If not to set `zipfile = None`, size of exe file becomes really small and it has problems with dependencies. Initial answer is edited accordingly.

Comment: can you post code for "watt.py"?  the dependencies i am referring to are python modules though, not dlls. and just for clarification, everything works fine on my computer - the problems only occur when i try to run on a computer without python.

Comment: Watt.py is just one line: `print("Hello World!")`. BTW, exe file size should be at least few megabytes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4587/discussion-between-alexey-and-ben)

Comment: Ben, we need to avoid discussions in comments. Let's go to chat it is [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4587/discussion-between-alexey-and-ben)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your setup script for you. This will work

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# The targets to build
# create a target that says nothing about UAC - On Python 2.6+, this
# should be identical to "asInvoker" below.  However, for 2.5 and
# earlier it will force the app into compatibility mode (as no
# manifest will exist at all in the target.)
t1 = dict(script="findpath.py",
          dest_base="findpath",
          uac_info="requireAdministrator")
console = [t1]

# hack to make windows copies of them all too, but
# with '_w' on the tail of the executable.
windows = [{'script': "findpath.py",
            'uac_info': "requireAdministrator",
            },]

setup(
    version = "0.5.0",
    description = "py2exe user-access-control",
    name = "py2exe samples",
    # targets to build
    windows = windows,
    console = console,
    #the options is what you fail to include it will instruct py2exe to include these modules explicitly
    options={"py2exe":
               {"includes": ["sip","os","shutil"]}
              }
    )
```